# ServiceWorker переопределяет UserAgent

Tags: javascript, service

Проблема такая, что мне надо получить доступ к ответу сервера в ServiceWorker, я делаю это в событии fetch (ничего не меняя, просто fetch(e.request)). Но дело в том, что из-за этого запрос уходит с дефолтным UserAgent, а мой кастомный UserAgent просто исчезает. Можно как-то отправить запрос из события fetch с сохранением UserAgent?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585254/is-it-possible-to-modify-service-worker-cache-response-headers